# How to set title in customer navigation tab magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am creating custom customer navigation tab using my module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current"  name="customer-account-navigation-custom-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">link/index</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom link</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

When i click on my custom tab its page title is Billing Agreements how to set page title in my custom tab

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For set Page title of current link in customer account navigation page,
You have set Title inside controller file.
In Your case, Controller file link/index, so index.php file is your controller file.

Go to controller file,

```
namespace path/To/Your/File;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Billing Agreements'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: My custom tab is show before Dashboard link i want to add my tab at the end how can i do this

Comment: you can add attribute before or after inside customer_account.xml file with <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-custom-link" after="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link">

Comment: How to redirect customer login page when customer is not login & run url in broswer?

Answer (score 7):

Your `link_index` layout file should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">   
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <head>
        <title>YOUR PAGE CUSTOM TITLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">YOUR CONTENT TITLE</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_EXTENSION\Block\Customer\YOURBLOCK" name="test" template="customer/test.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: My custom tab is show before Dashboard link i want to add my tab at the end how can i do this

Comment: How can we translate given title in <head> tag in this xml?

Answer (score 2):

You can set **after or before** with block tag and manage your link in navigation tab.Below is updated xml file check and verify.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current"  name="customer-account-navigation-custom-link" after="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">link/index</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom link</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```